# Network Request Failed - React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

So for no reason, I can not read any json data from my local server. There is no message in the log cat indicating that something is wrong.

Here is what I am doing. I first start the localhost server as

```
json-server --watch db.json -p 3001 -d 2000
```

and then get this back which is good.

```
  \{^_^}/ hi!

  Loading db.json
  Done

  Resources
  http://localhost:3001/dishes
  http://localhost:3001/comments
  http://localhost:3001/promotions
  http://localhost:3001/leaders
  http://localhost:3001/feedback

  Home
  http://localhost:3001
```

Next, I start the react native app `npm run android` and see this in the emulator.

[image: android emulator]

I declare the base url as:

```
  export const baseUrl ='http://IP_GOES_HERE:3001/';
```

My ip address hasn't changed.

and this is my fetch file.

```
import * as ActionTypes from './ActionTypes';
import { baseUrl } from '../shared/baseUrl';

export const fetchComments = () => (dispatch) => {
    return fetch(baseUrl + 'comments')
    .then(response => {
        if (response.ok) {
          return response;
        } else {
          var error = new Error('Error ' + response.status + ': ' + response.statusText);
          error.response = response;
          throw error;
        }
      },
      error => {
            var errmess = new Error(error.message);
            throw errmess;
      })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(comments => dispatch(addComments(comments)))
    .catch(error => dispatch(commentsFailed(error.message)));
};

export const commentsFailed = (errmess) => ({
    type: ActionTypes.COMMENTS_FAILED,
    payload: errmess
});

export const addComments = (comments) => ({
    type: ActionTypes.ADD_COMMENTS,
    payload: comments
});

export const fetchDishes = () => (dispatch) => {

    dispatch(dishesLoading());

    return fetch(baseUrl + 'dishes')
    .then(response => {
        if (response.ok) {
          return response;
        } else {
          var error = new Error('Error ' + response.status + ': ' + response.statusText);
          error.response = response;
          throw error;
        }
      },
      error => {
            var errmess = new Error(error.message);
            throw errmess;
      })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(dishes => dispatch(addDishes(dishes)))
    .catch(error => dispatch(dishesFailed(error.message)));
};

export const dishesLoading = () => ({
    type: ActionTypes.DISHES_LOADING
});

export const dishesFailed = (errmess) => ({
    type: ActionTypes.DISHES_FAILED,
    payload: errmess
});

export const addDishes = (dishes) => ({
    type: ActionTypes.ADD_DISHES,
    payload: dishes
});

export const fetchPromos = () => (dispatch) => {

    dispatch(promosLoading());

    return fetch(baseUrl + 'promotions')
    .then(response => {
        if (response.ok) {
            return response;
        } else {
            var error = new Error('Error ' + response.status + ': ' + response.statusText);
            error.response = response;
            throw error;
        }
        },
        error => {
            var errmess = new Error(error.message);
            throw errmess;
        })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(promos => dispatch(addPromos(promos)))
    .catch(error => dispatch(promosFailed(error.message)));
};

export const promosLoading = () => ({
    type: ActionTypes.PROMOS_LOADING
});

export const promosFailed = (errmess) => ({
    type: ActionTypes.PROMOS_FAILED,
    payload: errmess
});

export const addPromos = (promos) => ({
    type: ActionTypes.ADD_PROMOS,
    payload: promos
});

export const fetchLeaders = () => (dispatch) => {

    dispatch(leadersLoading());

    return fetch(baseUrl + 'leaders')
    .then(response => {
        if (response.ok) {
            return response;
        } else {
            var error = new Error('Error ' + response.status + ': ' + response.statusText);
            error.response = response;
            throw error;
        }
        },
        error => {
            var errmess = new Error(error.message);
            throw errmess;
        })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(leaders => dispatch(addLeaders(leaders)))
    .catch(error => dispatch(leadersFailed(error.message)));
};

export const leadersLoading = () => ({
    type: ActionTypes.LEADERS_LOADING
});

export const leadersFailed = (errmess) => ({
    type: ActionTypes.LEADERS_FAILED,
    payload: errmess
});

export const addLeaders = (leaders) => ({
    type: ActionTypes.ADD_LEADERS,
    payload: leaders
});

export const postFavorite = (dishId) => (dispatch) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        dispatch(addFavorite(dishId));
    }, 2000);
}

export const addFavorite = (dishId) => ({
    type: ActionTypes.ADD_FAVORITE,
    payload: dishId
});

export const addComment = (comment) => ({
    type: ActionTypes.ADD_COMMENT,
    payload: comment
});

export const postComment = (dishId, rating, comment, author) => (dispatch) => {
    const newComment = {
        dishId: dishId,
        rating: rating,
        author: author,
        comment: comment
    };
    newComment.date = new Date().toISOString();

    return fetch(baseUrl + 'comments', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify(newComment),
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        credentials: "same-origin"
    })
    .then(response => {
        if(response.ok) {
            return response;
        } else {
            var error = new Error('Error' + response.status + ': ' + response.statusText);
            error.response = response;
            throw error;
        }
    },
    error => {
        throw error;
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(response => setTimeout(() => {dispatch(addComment(response))}, 2000))
    .catch(error => { console.log('post comments', errorr.message); alert('Your comment cannot be posted\nError: ' + error.message); });
};
```

Everything was good. Why do I get this? I cleaned the project but still nothing

```
./gradlew clean
```

Thanks,
Theo.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be that your json-server is serving data at `localhost:3001`, but the android emulator's localhost is different than your computer's localhost.

You need to have json-server serve data at your local ip address, so the mobile device can access it across the LAN. You do that by entering the host IP address on the command line.

Instead of:

> json-server --watch db.json -p 3001

Use:

> json-server --watch db.json -p 3001 **-H [your_local_IP]**

Then your mobile can access the data across the LAN.